# Portfolio holder at 100% receiving odd margins

Tags: html, css, margins, portfolio

I'm in the process of remaking my website, my coding knowledge isn't the best but I know enough to manage my own website.

I've just run into a problem with the portfolio section of my website. I've defined the width of my container to and the width for the individual folios to 33% and for some reason it doesn't fill the entire screen and I'm getting an odd margin on the right hand side of the screen.

If someone could kindly help me resolve this issue I'd be very grateful!

Best wishes,

Matt

HTML

```
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">

  <div id="portfolio">

        <a href="curry_for_change.php"><div class="portfolio_image_wrap">
            <img src="images/test_image_2.png" alt="Curry For Change" />
            <h3 class="portfolio_description">Curry For Change</h3>
        </div></a>

        <a href="move_me_on.php"><div class="portfolio_image_wrap">
            <img src="images/test_image_2.png" alt="Move Me On" />
            <h3 class="portfolio_description">Move Me On</h3>
        </div></a>

       <a href="move_me_on.php"><div class="portfolio_image_wrap">
            <img src="images/test_image_2.png" alt="Ceviche" />
            <h3 class="portfolio_description">Ceviche</h3>
        </div></a>

        <a href="the_value_engineers.php"><div class="portfolio_image_wrap">
            <img src="images/test_image_2.png" alt="Designing a Better A&E" />
            <h3 class="portfolio_description">The Value Engineers</h3>
        </div></a>

        <a href="the_house.php"><div class="portfolio_image_wrap">
            <img src="images/test_image_2.png" alt="The House" />
            <h3 class="portfolio_description">The House London</h3>
        </div></a>

        <a href="walk_free.php"><div class="portfolio_image_wrap">
            <img src="images/test_image_2.png" alt="Walk Free" />
            <h3 class="portfolio_description">Walk Free</h3>
        </div></a>

         <a href="christmas14.php"><div class="portfolio_image_wrap">
            <img src="images/test_image_2.png" alt="Christmas 2014" />
            <h3 class="portfolio_description">Christmas 2014</h3>
        </div></a>

         <a href="sue_ryder.php"><div class="portfolio_image_wrap">
            <img src="images/test_image_2.png" alt="Sue Ryder" />
            <h3 class="portfolio_description">Sue Ryder</h3>
        </div></a>

        <a href="tesco_charity_partnership.php"><div        class="portfolio_image_wrap">
            <img src="images/test_image_2.png" alt="Tesco Charity Partnership" />
            <h3 class="portfolio_description">Tesco Charity Partnership</h3>
        </div></a>


 </div>
```

CSS

```
 * {
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
 }

#portfolio {
width:100%;
height:auto;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
 }


  .portfolio_image_wrap {
position:relative;
max-width:33%;
height:auto;
top:0;
left:0;
float:left;
 }

 .portfolio_image_wrap img {
height:auto;
max-width:100%;

  }

 .portfolio_description {
display:none;
background:#FF0066;
max-width:100%;
height:auto;
padding:10px;
text-decoration:none;
font-size:0px;
color:#fff;
position:absolute;
top:0px;
left:0px;
visibility:hidden;
opacity:0;
 }

 .portfolio_image_wrap:hover .portfolio_description {
display:block;
visibility:visible;
font-size:18px;
opacity:1;
  }
```

Here is a JS Fiddle version of my site development:

https://jsfiddle.net/hpq0s651/2/

Comment: sorry but this is not full code. please provide live demo link or working jsfiddle.ty

Comment: Sorry as I mentioned I'm a bit of a rookie, does this help? https://jsfiddle.net/hpq0s651/2/

Comment: Hopefully you'll be able to see the issue I'm experiencing now, odd margins around the portfolio images... I've probably done something completely idiotic to cause this, so feel free to throw insults my way ha!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here:

```
.portfolio_image_wrap {
    position:relative;
    max-width:33%;   /*try to set width: 33%; instead of max-width*/
    height:auto;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    float:left;
 }
```

## UPDATE:

```
width: 33.33%;
```

Comment: that doesn't seem to have made any difference. Thanks for the suggestion though! does this help: https://jsfiddle.net/hpq0s651/2/

Comment: Omg why am is so dumb. i tried to figured it out for minutes, and the problem was so simple!!

100 / 3 = 33.33%, not just 33%!!!

So 0.33 * 3 = 0.99, the strange margin that you couldn't explain why was there! ahaha

Comment: I didn't realise you could do .33 in web coding! I'm still getting an odd margin top and bottom though, do I need to change something with the height property?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
   #portfolio {
      width:100%;
      height:auto;
      margin-left:auto;
      margin-right:auto;
      border:none !important;
      outline:none !important;
```

}

```
  .portfolio_image_wrap {
      position:relative;
      max-width:33%;
      height:auto;
      top:0;
      left:0;
      float:left;
      border:none !important;
      outline:none !important;
     }
```

Comment: This didn't work, Mattia Nocerino helped with the 100% by making the max-width 33.33% (see comment below) that worked a treat but I'm getting margins above and below each row now. Not sure why ha!